# Worried deeply about my criminal record. Can someone tell me If I should be this worried?

Tags: software-development, canada, software, software-engineering

I just turned 24 a few weeks ago, and it's starting to worry me more deeply. When I was 19 I committed a serious crime. I can tell you that I wouldn't have done this ever, but it was due to a psychotic episode. I went insane, and all I ended up with was a robbery criminal record. The story behind what I did screams insane but I feel like it isn't justifiable. If someone were to actually dig deep enough and look at the report they would literally think I was insane. When I read it I thought that to myself, but I feel like they wouldn't want me to be near them. One aspect was in the report I robbed a subway with a demand note, and when they said "no", I walked to the next store that was in the same plaza and did the same thing. A real robber would've left the scene after the first fail. I was fighting psychotic episodes..

I spent 10 months in prison and recently finished probation after prison. So I would have to wait 10 years for a record suspension in Canada . Which is basically a thing where a criminal record is "forgiven" and set aside from other criminal records. So if a job does a background search it doesn't show.

I know no one who in this position in real life, all the people online seem to be from United states. I seriously need some more insight into this problem. I've spent many hours looking up different queries on Google  / Youtube / Reddit. I tried my best to reach out to people, but the one thing that concerns me the most is:

**How each record suspension isn't done automatically but on a case by case basis**

There's actually no guarantee I'll get a record suspension.

I was planning on going to university, maybe pursuing a PhD in computer science/computer engineering. But what's the point if I end up with a criminal record for the rest of my life? It feels awfully risky and I know it's actually still possible to get employed, even google hired someone who had a robbery criminal record. I'm missing out on the reality of this situation. I sometimes ask myself... "Why would anyone hire a felon? When there's so many others who aren't felons"

I know my options. I love Canada enough to never leave, I can still join the military or work in the trades. But what if I want to try out a academia job? Is it worth it to even go to university again or should I cut my losses and know my place? I know a job where sensitive data is being held is more likely to discriminate, but there must be tech jobs that would hire, right?

Comment: Sorry, but this is a classic close because we can't answer specifics on Canadian Law or on a Companies policy on hiring people with convictions. Best of luck, it sounds like you are trying to walk the right path, but we cannot help.

Comment: how common are background checks in Canada?
From what I gather from the outside, they are pretty common in the US.
But in Germany, that only gets checked for relevant jobs.
so you could work in IT, but if you were to work in IT for police/military or other security related stuff, they would check and disqualify you.

Comment: @Benjamin practically every job asks "Do you have a criminal record for which you have not been pardoned"

Comment: Id advise researching how to apply with a criminal record.
a quick google search gave me:
https://www.adecco.ca/en-ca/blog/how-to-find-a-job-when-you-have-a-criminal-record/

Also, if you reword your question to something like: I have a criminal record, how do I maximise my chances to land a job?
that should be ontopic here.

Comment: Academia might not care too much about your criminal background if you can go straight from a PhD to a post-doctoral working for the same professors that sponsored your PhD. I think asking about the prospects for someone with a criminal background in Canadian academia are probably better suited for the Academia StackExchange site, though.

Comment: I would suggest you to ask this question on Academia.SE. Also, I think getting a PhD is an option for you. "_So I would have to wait 10 years for a record suspension in Canada"_" If you go to college this fall, then get a master's, then PhD. 4 years for bachelor's, 2 years for master's, 4 years for PhD. It'll be ten years for you to get PhD. By that time, your record is suspended. No one in Academia would care about your record anymore. Please think about it.

Comment: I know a number of people with criminal records. Many are able to find employment. There are companies that specifically hire such because they turn out to be excellent employees. Expand your search.

Answer (score 5):

> Can someone tell me If I should be this worried?

You already know very well the answer for employment background check in Canada. You even wrote that in the comment section below your post.

However, I suggest that you should stay positive, try your best, and hope for the best.

---

> Is it worth it to even go to university again or should I cut my losses and know my place?

Yes, it is. A college degree may be helpful at least when you want to start and run a business on your own.

In addition, you also express your interest in working in the IT industry. In this case, you can also explore the option of learning from coding bootcamps (for a shorter duration) instead of going to college (even though going to college is still a good option).

**Try To Work as a Freelancer:**

Once you get some good coding skills from either a bootcamp or college, you can try to work as a freelancer to develop websites, mobile apps, graphic designs, etc... either for yourself or for clients. After you earn more work experiences, you can either start your own solid business or apply for jobs elsewhere.

---

Maybe, you should stay positive and hopeful that with gainful employment, in 10 years, your record will be cleared or suspended.

---

BTW, I hope that you have already tried to get some professional help to make sure that this **psychotic episode** won't happen again.

This will be very helpful to your mental health, your life, and your career.

Answer (score 2):

One advantage of going back to school is that it's more years with a clean record and demonstrated ability to focus and achieve. The farther in the past the event is, the less weight it will carry. And you'll be a more valuable employee when you have higher level skills.

Downside of course is cost, and not having a significant income for those years (unless you can arrange something part time, possibly on campus where you are already a known quantity). But this feels like it might be worth pursuing.

Another thing to investigate: I don't know what services are available in Canada to assist those with a history of either crime or mental illness in re-entering society. There may be organizations which can give you guidance. It's certainly worth searching for them.

You may have to accept menial jobs for a while until you build a history of trustworthiness. There may not be a shortcut; actions do have consequences, even when one can argue they weren't entirely your fault. But all you can do is keep trying, keep applying, and hope for the opportunity to prove who you now are.

Answer (score 0):

> "Why would anyone hire a felon? when theres so many others who aren't felons"

They wouldn't all else being equal. It's a risk they have no need to take.

Comment: But all else is rarely equal. And some believe in giving folks a chance to recover from early mistakes. Only way to find out is to send out applications, and be prepared with a good explanation of what happened and why it won't happen again

Comment: @keshlam yep, it's not equal, op is an ex-convict with no special skills to mitigate against that. Sooner he/she comes to terms with that pragmatically the sooner they can try and move forwards with life.